# Accessing NavParams inside a provider,

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, leaflet

I am trying to access NavParams inside a provider, but I know importing the NavParams wouldn't solve the problem.

Short info about my application, the user input their name and address, there will be a pin on the map base on the address and when the user click on the pin, an alert saying the name of the pin.

Here is my create-event.ts where I push the name.

```
toMap() {
  this.navCtrl.push('MapPage', {eName: this.eventDetail.eventName});
}
```

Retrieve on Map.ts and push to markers.ts

```
public eName: string;

constructor (...) {
this.eName = this.navParams.get('eName');
}

addMarker() {
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Add Marker',
  message: "Enter Adress",
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'Address',
      placeholder: 'Enter Address'
    },
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data => {

        this.geoCodeandAdd(data.address);
        this.retrieveAddress(data.address);
      }
    }
  ]
});
prompt.present();
}
geoCodeandAdd(address) {
this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(address)
  .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[]) => {

  this.markersProvider.saveMarker(coordinates[0]);
  this.navCtrl.push('MarkerProvider', {eName: this.eName});
})
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
  loadMarkers() {
this.markersProvider.getAllMarkers().subscribe((markers: any) => {
  markers.forEach(singlemarker => {
    let markerGroup = leaflet.featureGroup();

    let marker: any = leaflet
      .marker([singlemarker.latitude, singlemarker.longitude])
      .on("click", () => {
        alert(singlemarker.message);
      });
    markerGroup.addLayer(marker);
    this.map.addLayer(markerGroup);
  });
});
}
```

My marker provider .ts

```
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from "angularfire2/firestore";

@Injectable()
export class MarkersProvider {
  public eName: string;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log("Hello MarkersProvider Provider");
    this.eName = this.navParams.get('eName');
  }

  saveMarker(coords) {
    this.afs
      .collection("markers")
      .add({
        latitude: coords.latitude,
        longitude: coords.longitude,
        message: this.eName,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("Added");
      });
  }

  getAllMarkers() {
    return this.afs.collection("markers").valueChanges();
  }
}
```

stack trace

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Content -> NavController]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Content -> NavController]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Content -> NavController]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Content -> NavController]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController!
    at _NullInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:19)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1675:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1617:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1485:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1675:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1617:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1485:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11270:25)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11311:68)
    at _createProviderInstance$1     (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11281:26)
at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52760:16)
at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52753:14)
at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52800:59
at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33)
at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
```

Is there a way to use navparams inside the provider.

Comment: Instead of trying to get your marker eName value from the provider, you should set this value. Whenever there is a change on your marker name, just call your provider and set the value : this.MarkersProvider.ename = "Name"

Comment: Map.ts is the root component ?

Comment: Have you tried to use localStorage?

Comment: hi, i need an elaborate detail about that, i just started my ionic this month, map.ts is a page module, i dont know anymore implementation and how to use localstorage as this is from a tutorial, but i tweak it to satisfy my need

Comment: @saperlipopette, wait, is this correct? `getName(name) { this.eName = name}` on provider, and `this.markerProvider.getName(this.eName)` on MapPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need navParams to pass values to provider. You need to just pass it to relevant method in your provider as simple argument of function.

In your Map.ts:

```
public eName: string;

constructor (...) {
this.eName = this.navParams.get('eName');
}

addMarker() {
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Add Marker',
  message: "Enter Adress",
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'Address',
      placeholder: 'Enter Address'
    },
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data => {

        this.geoCodeandAdd(data.address);
        this.retrieveAddress(data.address);
      }
    }
  ]
});
prompt.present();
}
geoCodeandAdd(address) {
this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(address)
  .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[]) => {

  // here pass eName as argument:
  this.markersProvider.saveMarker(coordinates[0], this.eName); 
  // removed this: this.navCtrl.push('MarkerProvider', {eName: this.eName});
})
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
  loadMarkers() {
this.markersProvider.getAllMarkers().subscribe((markers: any) => {
  markers.forEach(singlemarker => {
    let markerGroup = leaflet.featureGroup();

    let marker: any = leaflet
      .marker([singlemarker.latitude, singlemarker.longitude])
      .on("click", () => {
        alert(singlemarker.message);
      });
    markerGroup.addLayer(marker);
    this.map.addLayer(markerGroup);
  });
});
}
```

Now in your provider, modify the method that uses eName:

```
// remove this: import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from "angularfire2/firestore";

@Injectable()
export class MarkersProvider {
  // remove this: public eName: string;
  // modify injections as you don't need nav things in your provider:
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    console.log("Hello MarkersProvider Provider");
    // remove this: this.eName = this.navParams.get('eName');
  }

  // here in this method add argument:
  saveMarker(coords, eName) {
    this.afs
      .collection("markers")
      .add({
        latitude: coords.latitude,
        longitude: coords.longitude,
        message: eName,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("Added");
      });
  }

  getAllMarkers() {
    return this.afs.collection("markers").valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you this is so much better than what i have in mind

Comment: No problem;) navParams are used for Pages (Components) since they don’t exist in memory before you push such page into nav stack. Providers do exist in memory and they normally dont get destroyed so you can call methods and pass parameters as arguments.